# Swift Firebase -How to add an observer to viewDidLoad, remove it in viewDidDisappear, then read it again in viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I have a chat log and I initially had my `.observe( .childAdded)` listener called in `viewDidLoad` and removed it in `viewDidDisappear` but after reading this comment [image] [from this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00i6s.png) I moved the listener to `viewWillAppear` and now whenever I switch views and come back the listener runs all over again and my tableData gets filled up with the same info twice.

For eg. say i have only 1 message in the chat from the other user that says "hello". If the chat vc is in tabTwo, the very first time the vc appears the code will run and the collectionView's datasource will have 1 message that says "hello". If I press a different tab and come back to tabTwo there will now be 2 messages that say "hello" (the same exact message) because the code ran all over again. This becomes a serious problem if there are 100 messages. That means there will be 200 messages and it'll keep adding up every time I switch tabs and come back.

Am I also supposed to clear the tableData and reload the collectionView in viewDidDisappear when I remove the observer so that way all the data isn't duplicated when viewWillAppear is called again? That's what I did to resolve the issue but that doesn't seem correct.

Is there a better way to call the observer in viewDidLoad then read it again in viewWillAppear without causing my collectionView to duplicate the data?

```
let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid!
let toId = "theOtherUsersId"

var tableData = [Message]()
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messageIds")

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    ref.child(currentUserId).child(toId).observe( .childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key

        self?.getMessagesWith(messageId)
    })
}

func getMessagesWith(_ messageId: String) {

    Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let message = Message(dict: dict)

        self?.tableData.append(message)
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    tableData.removeAll() // something seems wrong about doing this
    collectionView.reloadData()
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GaloTorresSevilla comments under my original answer was correct. He suggested to move the observer to viewWillAppear and just use the messageId to filter out any messages that already exists in the tableData. He was 100% correct because when I switch back to the tab no data is duplicated

```
let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid!
let toId = "theOtherUsersId"

var tableData = [Message]()
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messageIds")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // nothing to do here
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    ref.child(currentUserId).child(toId).observe( .childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key

        // in viewWillAppear if the tableData contains the messageId above then return
        if self.tableData.contains (where: { $0.messageId ?? “” == messageId }) {
            return
        }
        self?.getMessagesWith(messageId)
    })
}

func getMessagesWith(_ messageId: String) {

    Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let message = Message(dict: dict)

        self?.tableData.append(message)
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    ref.child(currentUserId).child(toId).removeAllObservers()
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't get any duplicates but how exactly will you get the new messages in this case? Your observers are being removed in `viewDidDisappear` and initialized back in `viewWillAppear`. Then if a new message comes, how will this message be added if the new `viewWillAppear` observer does not call `getMessagesWith` method? I think that the best way for you to do it is have a UID for each message and do a comparison to check if the message is already in the dataSource

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but when I did it the new message got added.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla that’s a good idea to check each messageId

Comment: If you are still getting the messages it is most probably because you have a strong reference in `viewDidLoad`. That will cause a leak at some point. I really think that a comparable with message UIDs is the best option.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla I found out why everything was working even though it wasn't supposed. The observers weren't getting removed so that empty ref I have in viewWIllAppear wasn't doing anything because the one from viewDidLoad was still being used. Anyhow I switched everything over to viewWillAppear and used the messageId to filter like you suggested and it 100% works. If you post that as an answer I will accept because it works. I'm also going to delete this answer. I'm only keeping it here to contact you letting you know your idea worked.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't do much. I only provided a suggestion and you did all the work. But I am very glad you got it to work and my comment was helpful.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help!

Comment: I deleted the incorrect answer Ian’s  updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.